# PCL Harris Keypoints

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a sort of supported way to use PCL's spiffy new HarrisKeypoint3D keypoints with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12202/pcl-harris-keypoints/) by [DanDee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1241/dandee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanDee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1241/dandee/) on 2011-12-04**:
perception_pcl_unstable appears to be too old to have the harris keypoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check out perception_pcl_unstable and modify it to use the latest trunk release. (at your own risk) Comment out the revision line in Makefile and adjust the manifest to pcl-1.4

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0